# Can't get 'underscore' to work with parse server

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I just migrated a Parse Server, and everything works, except cloud code. I have come to the understanding that it's because in my main.js I require the library "Underscore".

This is my cloud code function:

```
    Parse.Cloud.define("ReadyUp", function(request, response) {
var _ = require('underscore');
    var fbid = request.user.get("fbid");
    var query = new Parse.Query("Spel");
    query.equalTo("lobby", fbid);
    query.find().then(function(results) {
        _.each(results, function(spel) {
            spel.addUnique("ready", fbid);
        });
        return Parse.Object.saveAll(results);
    }).then(function(result) {
        response.success(result);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

The code worked with no error before the migration. I'm guessing the require doesn't find the right folder. To give you folder structure it looks like this:

Cloudcode location:
mainfolder->cloud->main.js

Underscore library:
mainfolder->node_modules->underscore(folder)

Is the code faulty or is the structure of folders faulty?

Thanks in advance!

/Martin

Comment: *"migrated a Parse Server"* ... what does that actually mean?

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry if you didn't catch that. Basically, I've used the service parse.com which is a backend with database and now transfered these to Heroku as well as MongoDB

Comment: @MartinKjellberg did you add underscore in the package.json dependencies ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to point to correct underscore file. I did the following:

```
var _ = require('../node_modules/underscore/underscore.js')
```

Answer (score 1):

Add underscore to your dependencies in `package.json`, either manually or run `npm install underscore --save`

This will result in a line like this:

```
"underscore": "^1.8.3"
```

From then, you can actually do this

```
var _ = require('underscore');
```